# How to update "Last commit" in my developer story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Currently, [my developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/35070) includes the following GitHub repository reference:

[image: last update: Dec 08 2017]

However, the last update [is actually December 26th](https://github.com/phihag/bup/commits/master). How can I manually trigger an update, or (preferably) set it up to update automatically?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way to do this, that's a bit rubbish. You can add the project manually instead of importing from GitHub which will mean there's no commit shown at all.

Comment: Github is showing no commits on Dec 8 for me... but is it because I'm GMT -3 possibly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't have a way for you to manually trigger an update, but that is a great idea and I will bring it up to the team.

We do have a scheduled task that syncs your commit info from the github api to your developer story every 7 days. The reason your commits were not being synced is because you did not have a github username set on your developer story/profile. I went ahead and set it for you as **phihag**. Your commits should now automatically update every 7 days as long as the github user has new commit activity associated with the imported repositories on your developer story.

Comment: Thanks! Can't stackoverflow detect the user name when importing the GitHub repositories and set it automatically?

Comment: @phihag yes, it should be! Looks like that is not working properly. Will push a fix. Thanks!